# FullCalendarBundle displays an error after installing it in symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, fullcalendar

I installed fullcalendarbundle, and I configured it as it is mentioned on the Github, but when I run it, 
it shows nothing on the screen except [null, null] :

Or it should show me a calendar where I can add events and save them in the database.

Here is my listener:

```
namespace Doctix\MedecinBundle\EventListener;

 use Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Schedule;
 use Toiba\FullCalendarBundle\Entity\Event;
 use Toiba\FullCalendarBundle\Event\CalendarEvent;

 use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class FullCalendarListener
{
/**
 * @var EntityManager
 *
 */
private $em;

/**
 * @var UrlGeneratorInterface
 */
private $router;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->router = $router;
}
  /**
 * @param CalendarEvent $calendar
 */
public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendar)
{
    $startDate = $calendar->getDateDebut();
    $endDate = $calendar->getDateFin();
    $filters = $calendar->getFilters();

    // You may want do a custom query to populate the calendar
    // b.beginAt is the start date in the booking entity
   $schedules = $this->em->getRepository(Schedule::class)
        ->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->andWhere('s.date_debut BETWEEN :date_debut and :date_fin')
        ->setParameter('date_debut', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->setParameter('date_fin', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->getQuery()->getResult();

    foreach($schedules as $schedule) {

        // create an event with the booking data
        $scheduleEvent = new Event(
            $schedule->getTitle(),
            $schedule->getDateDebut(),
            $schedule->getDateFin() // If end date is null or not defined, it create an all day event
        );

        $scheduleEvent->setUrl(
            $this->router->generate('schedule_index', array(
                'id' => $schedule->getId(),
            ))
        );

        /*
         * For more information see : Toiba\FullCalendarBundle\Entity\Event
         * and : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object
         */
        // $bookingEvent->setBackgroundColor($booking['bgColor']);
        // $bookingEvent->setCustomField('borderColor', $booking['bgColor']);

        // finally, add the booking to the CalendarEvent for displaying on the calendar
        $calendar->addEvent($scheduleEvent);
    }
}
```

}
And here is my entity:

```
    namespace Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

  /**
  * CalendarEvent
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="schedule")
  * 
  )
 */

class Schedule
 {
  /**
  * @var int
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
 private $id;
  /**
  * @var string
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
  */
  private $title;
  /**
  * @var \DateTime
  *
   *@ORM\Column(name="date_debut", type="datetime", nullable=true)
   */
  private $date_debut;
  /**
  * @var \DateTime
  *
  *@ORM\Column(name="date_fin", type="datetime", nullable=true)
  */
   private $date_fin;

  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
  */
 private $medecin;


/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}
/**
 * @param string $title
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateDebut()
{
    return $this->date_debut;
}
 /**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateFin()
{
    return $this->date_fin;
}
/**
 * @param \DateTime $date_debut
 */
public function setDateDebut($date_debut)
{
    $this->date_debut = $date_debut;
}
/**
 * @param \DateTime $date_fin
 */
public function setDateFin($date_fin)
{
    $this->date_fin = $date_fin;
}

 /**
 * Set medecin
 *
 * @param \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin $medecin
 * @return Schedule
 */
public function setMedecin(\Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin $medecin)
{
    $this->medecin = $medecin;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get medecin
 *
 * @return \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin 
 */
public function getMedecin()
{
    return $this->medecin;
}
```

And here is the rendering of my page:
[rendering of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82WIU.jpg)
[and following the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HZnv.jpg)
Thank you, if you need another file, tell me

here is my js file:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar({
        events: '/schedule',
        locale: 'fr',
        header: {
            left: 'prev, next, today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
        },
     /*   buttonText: {
                        today: 'aujourd''hui',
                        month: 'mois',
                        week:  'semaine',
                        day:   'jour',
                        list:  'liste'
        } */
        //weekends: false,
        timezone: ('Africa/Bamako'),
        businessHours: {
            start: '09:00',
            end: '18:00',
            dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        },
        allDaySlot: true,
        defaultView: 'month',
        lazyFetching: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        selectable: true,
        /*timeFormat: {
            agenda: 'h:mmt',
            '': 'h:mmt'
        },*/
        /*columnFormat:{
            month: 'ddd',
            week: 'ddd D/M',
            day: 'dddd'
        },*/
        editable: true,
        eventDurationEditable: true,
     /*   eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
            element.click(function(){
                $("#calendar_modal").html(moment(event.title));
                $("#calendar_modal").html(moment(event.date_debut).format("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP"));
                $("#calendar_modal").html(moment(event.date_fin).format("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP"));
                $("eventLink").attr('href', event.url);
                $("eventContent").dialog({ modal: true, title: event.title, width:350});
            });

        } */
    });
});
```

And you're probably going to ask me why I did not call the url: fc-load-events, because this one always shows me the two [    ] tags on a blank page.

Comment: In the doc, in your entity, it's talking about extending AncaRebeca\FullCalendarBundle\Model\FullCalendarEvent not the event... Is it normal ?  https://github.com/ancarebeca/FullCalendarBundle#3-create-your-calendar-event-class-

Comment: In the listener near `andWhere('b.beginAt` in `createQueryBuilder` change `b` by `s` (like Schedule first letter of your entity) and `b.beginAt` by `s.date_debut`. Then near `$scheduleEvent = new Event(` change `getBeginAt` by `getDateDebut` same for end

Comment: It does not change anything yet, always the same rendering

Comment: @MohamedSacko can you show your listener

Comment: @ThéoAttali, I edited my listener according to your recommendations

Comment: To show Network monitor and see the symfony error, press `Ctrl + Shift + E` on Firefox or `Control + Shift + I` on Chrome then reload the page. Finally click on `fc-load-events` and select the Response or Preview tab

Comment: I think your error is the `schedule_index` that should be `schedule_show`

Comment: Hi @ThéoAttali, yes indeed, it had to be schedule_show, and with that I had the schedule view on my calendar that kind of a long time ago, and when I clicked on an event and after getting back on the calendar nothing is displayed

Comment: Maybe my problem comes from my javascript file, I do not know, I'm totally lost. I added my main js file

Comment: put the js in the template like [here](https://github.com/toiba/FullCalendarBundle/blob/master/doc/doctrine-crud.md) or use `fos js routing` to put js in your main.js file

Comment: Hi @ThéoAttali, Thank you very much for everything, it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CRUD is done use this EventListener and modify all Booking or booking by your entity name.

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\Booking;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Toiba\FullCalendarBundle\Entity\Event;
use Toiba\FullCalendarBundle\Event\CalendarEvent;

class FullCalendarListener
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @var UrlGeneratorInterface
     */
    private $router;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @param CalendarEvent $calendar
     */
    public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendar)
    {
        $startDate = $calendar->getStart();
        $endDate = $calendar->getEnd();
        $filters = $calendar->getFilters();

        // You may want do a custom query to populate the calendar
        // b.beginAt is the start date in the booking entity
        $bookings = $this->em->getRepository(Booking::class)
            ->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->andWhere('b.beginAt BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')
            ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->getQuery()->getResult();

        foreach($bookings as $booking) {

            // create an event with the booking data
            $bookingEvent = new Event(
                $booking->getTitle(),
                $booking->getBeginAt(),
                $booking->getEndAt() // If end date is null or not defined, it create an all day event
            );

            $bookingEvent->setUrl(
                $this->router->generate('booking_show', array(
                    'id' => $booking->getId(),
                ))
            );

            /*
             * For more information see : Toiba\FullCalendarBundle\Entity\Event
             * and : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object
             */
            // $bookingEvent->setBackgroundColor($booking['bgColor']);
            // $bookingEvent->setCustomField('borderColor', $booking['bgColor']);

            // finally, add the booking to the CalendarEvent for displaying on the calendar
            $calendar->addEvent($bookingEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good evening, I did exactly as you said, but so far this shows me the empty calendar and just down the schedule list.

Comment: I edited my post and add a rendering image of my page. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @ThéoAttali, 
I wanted to ask you, if you have any idea about how to display the events created on the fullcalendar and saved in a database on a date picker for an appointment taking

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue you can use this bundle :

https://github.com/tattali/CalendarBundle

Comment: OK. I have to reinstall this bundle to zero or I just have to configure some parts?

Comment: Delete the previous bundle and install this one

Comment: Ok I did that, and it shows me : [{"title":"booking_1","start":"2018-07-16T12:00:00+00:00","allDay":false,"editable":false,"startEditable":false,"durationEditable":false,"overlap":true,"backgroundColor":"green","end":"2018-07-16T13:00:00+00:00","borderColor":"green"} ] and do I have to change my entity ?

Comment: I hope you find out how to proceed, but here is an example with doctrine https://github.com/toiba/FullCalendarBundle/blob/master/doc/doctrine-listener.md

Comment: Hi Théo Attali, as you suggested, I installed the Toiba bundle and it just showed me a calendar without events, just a calendar. The goal for me is to be able to add (edit and delete) events to from the calendar and save them in a database. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is several way to proceed but the easiest is by doing a basic CRUD. And add the url of the show when we click on an event

Comment: To do this you need to inject the router to the listener (same as entityManager)

Comment: Hi @Théo Attali, that's what I did by generating the CRUD, and the actions are executing, now how to incorporate his actions there in the calendar ?

Comment: and allow a doctor to fill his schedule, and add multiple events and save them. Thanks